# How to access the nth element in a 2d texture from a pixel shader in XNA

Tags: xna-4.0, fragment-shader

How can I access the nth element in a texture2d from a pixel shader? For example if I wanted to get the 5th vector4 from 10 x 10 texture2d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2D textures usually aren't addressed in terms like the "nth element".  The whole point of a 2D texture is that you want to access it using 2D coordinates.  If you want to send a 1D array to the shader I'd use a 1D texture.

That being said, you can compute it by something like this:

```
int x = n % textureWidth;
int y = n / textureWidth;                            // integer division
float u = (float(x) + 0.5) / float(textureWidth);    // map into 0-1 range
float v = (float(y) + 0.5) / float(textureHeight);
float4 result = tex2D(sampler, float2(u, v));
```

(This assumes you already know how to set up a sampler parameter in the shader and bind a texture to it from the application side.)

Comment: A 1d texture sounds perfect for my situation.  How does use them in XNA?

Comment: Shouldn't you add `0.5` to `float(x)` and `float(y)` before dividing? Otherwise you will get off-by-one errors, especially on a 10×10 texture.

Comment: @SamHocevar, good catch!  I'll edit to add that.